# How do I use JPA to select the record with the closest date?

Tags: spring-data

Let's say I have a collection of Rates that all inherit from an `AbstractRate`

```java
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "name")
@Table(name = "rates")
public abstract class AbstractRate {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Column(precision = 13, scale = 4)
    private BigDecimal value;
    @OneToOne
    private EffectiveDate effectiveDate;
    ...
}
```

And, that all have an EffectiveDate:

```java
@Entity
public class EffectiveDate {
    @Id
    private LocalDateTime date;
    ...
}
```

(I acknowledge that a separate date object is a little over-kill for this model, but it's allowing me to bind multiple rates and other figures in the database.)

Now, I'd like to get a specific Rate, say `SalaryRate`, that is effective as of a certain date.  I can do something like

```java
salaryRateRepository.findByEffectivedate(
     effectiveDateRepository.findTopByDateLessThanEqualOrderByDateDesc(sampleDate)
);
```

This should effectively give me a the `MAX(date)` and its matching Rate.  Is this the right way to query these things?  Some posts suggest

As an additional option, I have Querydsl setup and the repositories extend `QuerydslPredicateExecutor`.  However, I'm not really familiar with how Querydsl's syntax works.

Answer (score 0):

I think all is OK with `findTopByDateLessThanEqualOrderByDateDesc(sampleDate)`.

Another variants should be:

```java
@Query(value = "select * from effective_date ed where ed.date <= ?1 order by ed.date desc limit 1", nativeQuery = true)
EffectiveDate findEffectiveDate(LocalDateTime dateTime);
```

or

```java
Predicate p = QEffectiveDate.effectiveDate.date.loe(sampleDate);
Pageable page = new PageRequest(0, 1, new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "date"));
//...
EffectiveDate effectiveDate = effectiveDateRepository.findAll(p, page).getContent().stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
```

(not tested...)